# C++11 threads in class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pointer-to-member

i am using the c++11 thread library with classes, and it works fine.
I just need an explanation for this code so i understand it correctly.

My class.h

```
class foo {
  private:
    std::thread t1;
    void worker();
  public:
    void work();
};
```

the class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

void foo::worker() {
  std::cout << "worker..." << std::endl;
}

void foo::work() {
  t1 = std::thread(&foo::worker, this);
  t1.join();
}
```

and now the main.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  foo bar;
  bar.work();
}
```

What I don't really understand is the invocation of the class-function for the thread.
I use `std::thread(&foo::work, this)` and interpret this call as follows:
The first parameter is the pointer to the function, but i dont know why i cant just call it
without the `&foo::` part.
The second parameter is the class itself that the thread knows the parent process?

I couldn't find a explaination for this. Only the code and i would like to understand it.
Thanks!

Comment: `t1 = std::thread(&foo::work, this);` shouldn't this be `t1 = std::thread(&foo::worker, this);` ??

Comment: @g-makulik Good call. As it is, this code is the start of a very nice [forkbomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forkbomb). The second call into `foo::work` should call `std::terminate`, though, since assigning to a joinable thread is [`disallowed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D). I'll add that if the OP wants to continue using a thread inside a class like this, among other concerns, they should check for `t1.joinable() == true` and handle the error accordingly.

Comment: @g-makulik, ups, that was a copy mistake in this editor. thanks for the hint

Comment: BTW, the declaration of `work` is missing its type decl. Too short to edit.

Comment: @sfjac thanks, i updated it!

Answer (score 3):

`&foo::work` is required because `work` is a member function that belongs to class `foo`. A (non-static) member function can only be accessed if also the object it belongs to is known.

The `this` parameter is a pointer to the object of which the method should be called.

Comment: @sfjac Because there is no function `work`. Work is a method of `foo` and not an independent function.

Comment: I understand that completely---as my answer shows---but the question is why the syntax isn't allowed. I believe `this->work` is allowed. Not sure why `work` by itself isn't sufficient as it seems unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

The address bit is just the syntax for expressing the address of a member function. I believe this could also be expressed as `this->worker`. I don't know why `worker` by itself is not allowed---it seems unambiguous, but that's C++.

You have to pass both the member function pointer and `this` so that the thread can invoke the member function on the correct object. Internally the thread holds a member function pointer, say `pmf` (pointing to `foo::worker`), and the object pointer, say `po` (pointing to the `this` that was passed). It needs to be able to invoke `(po->*pmf)()`, which result in `worker` being invoked on the correct object.